# In Xades4J, how to pretty-print the document before calculating the digest?

Tags: xades4j

In the code below, I call `sign()` against a `new DataObjectReference( "" )`.
This means Xades4j calculates the digest against the whole Document object.

But this also means it strips any whitespace, as the Document object doesn't contain whitespace information.

I tried using an `AnonymousDataObjectReference` instead (passing the string-serialized XML) but then the (XPath) Transform fails to parse the string.

I'd like to be able to pass a pretty-printed document to Xades4j, so that the output hash matches the final pretty-printed document hash.

```java
KeyingDataProvider kp = loadKeyStore();

DataObjectDesc obj = new DataObjectReference( "" )
        .withTransform( /*[...]*/ )
        .withDataObjectFormat( new DataObjectFormatProperty( MediaType.TEXT_XML ) );

try
{
    XadesSigner signer = new XadesBesSigningProfile( kp )
            .newSigner();

    Node signatureInformation = doc.getElementsByTagName( "sac:SignatureInformation" ).item( 0 );

    XadesSignatureResult signResult = signer.sign( new SignedDataObjects( obj ), signatureInformation );

    return signResult;
}
catch ( XAdES4jException e )
{
  //...
}
```